# MySQL Calculate New Field with Value from Another Row and Value from Current Row

Tags: sql, mysql, dataframe

I have a query for data on weekly performance for multiple warehouses where each row represents one week. In my query I would like to calculate a new column for the WeekOverWeek change (increase or decrease since last week) for the warehouse.

My Query currently returns this table:

```
SELECT
    Warehouse,
    Week,
    Rate 
FROM TableX 
WHERE...
```

| Warehouse | Week | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 22 | 55.3 |
| A | 23 | 57.1 |
| A | 24 | 57.9 |
| B | 22 | 62.4 |
| B | 23 | 63.1 |
| B | 24 | 63.9 |
| C | 22 | 54.3 |
| C | 23 | 53.9 |
| C | 24 | 56.8 |

Could I use a Cursor or some other method to return a new field in the table as such:
[ Week Over Week should be calculated for that specific warehouse (CurrentWeek - LastWeek) / LastWeek ]

| Warehouse | Week | Rate | WoW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 22 | 55.3 | NULL |
| A | 23 | 57.1 | 0.0325 |
| A | 24 | 57.9 | 0.0140 |
| B | 22 | 62.4 | NULL |
| B | 23 | 63.1 | 0.0112 |
| B | 24 | 63.9 | 0.0127 |
| C | 22 | 54.3 | NULL |
| C | 23 | 53.9 | -0.0074 |
| C | 24 | 56.8 | 0.0538 |

I attempted to adjust my query something like...

```
SELECT
    Warehouse,
    Week,
    Rate,
    Rate / (SELECT Rate FROM TableX WHERE Week = Week - 1 AND Warehouse = Warehouse) - 1 AS WoW
FROM TableX
WHERE...
```

This generates a completely empty WoW column with no data.

Comment: Look into lag/lead.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can do this with the `LAG()` window function.

Comment: If not, use a self-join with the `ON` condition relating the weeks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MySQL 8, you are looking for `LAG`:

```
select tx.Warehouse
    , tx.Week
    , tx.Rate
    , (tx.Rate - LAG(tx.Rate, 1) over (partition by tx.Warehouse order by tx.Week)) / LAG(tx.Rate, 1) over (partition by tx.Warehouse order by tx.Week) WoW
from TableX tx
```

For something older, like v5.5, you can self join the table with some conditions to get the previous week:

```
select CurrentWeek.Warehouse
    , CurrentWeek.Week
    , CurrentWeek.Rate
    , (CurrentWeek.Rate - PrevWeek.Rate) / PrevWeek.Rate WoW
from TableX CurrentWeek
left join TableX PrevWeek
    on CurrentWeek.Warehouse = PrevWeek.Warehouse
    and CurrentWeek.Week - 1 = PrevWeek.Week
```

Comment: LAG worked exactly as I was hoping! Thank you, I did not know of this function before.